# Does iOS 8 include an NFC SDK for developers?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, nfc, iphone-6

Today, Apple announced eminent release of the iPhone 6, which will include a NFC chip.

Did Apple announce an NFC SDK for developers to utilize the technology?

Answer (score 4):

It does include `PKPayment` Class (it contains payment information encrypted in the payment token) and related classes Passport Kit,  which is what is used for payments. There are API's for no direct communications with the chip.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has not announced any new SDK other than WatchKit on today's event. iOS 8 and Xcode 6 (with iOS 8 SDK) has went GM though, so if it's not there, it won't be there for the final release of iOS 8.